# How to implement an outgoing interface on a sink object (C++)

Tags: c++, com, event-handling

I have a **predefined** TLB file, with IS8SimulationEvents wrapper method implementations, for instance:

```
inline HRESULT IS8SimulationEvents::S8SimulationReset ( ) {
    HRESULT _result = 0;
    _com_dispatch_method(this, 0x1, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_ERROR, (void*)&_result, NULL);
    return _result;
}
```

Using Oleview, I can see the **IConnectionPointContainer** interface attached to the COM object.

**Question:**

- How do I implement the outgoing interface on a sink object, for the client to receive event notification from the COM **object**

**Without:**

- ATL
- MFC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explain how to implement connections points sources/sinks in plain C http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c5.aspx

Probably the whole series of articles "COM in plain C" by Jeff Glatt are more than recommended if you want to understand COM at the low level.

PD: Lambdasoft Comet is a framework that implement COM wrappers that doesn't make use of ATL/MFC, it is pretty dated but if you want something simple it worth to take a look https://bitbucket.org/sofusmortensen/comet/ or http://www.lambdasoft.dk/comet/.

Comment: Thanks - can you produce a simple illustration?

Comment: Each article from CP contains a sample project, it is much better than anything that I can provide. Download it, compile and test what is it behavior, so you can hack around it.

Comment: Shame - the file is no longer available :(

Comment: The sample project is there, but you have to be a registered user.

Comment: OK Xhantt, thanks. But I'm actually looking for a pure C++ implementation. I've managed to automate the application, I just need to figure out how to adapt it to handle events notifications from the COM object Server...